# Find the greatest value of $E=\frac{a_1}{1+a_1^2}+\frac{a_2}{1+a_2^2}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2}$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

> Let $ n $ $(n\geq2)$ be an integer. Find the greatest possible value of the expression $$E=\frac{a_1}{1+a_1^2}+\frac{a_2}{1+a_2^2}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2}$$ if the positive real numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ satisfy $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n=\frac{n}{2}$. What are the values of $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ when the greatest value is achieved?

---

I want to know if my solution is correct.
**My solution:** Note that the expression $$E=\frac{a_1}{1+a_1^2}+\frac{a_2}{1+a_2^2}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2}$$ is homogeneous. Without the restriction $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n=\frac{n}{2}$, the highest value of $E$ is $\frac {n}{2}$ achieved when $a_1=a_2=...=a_n=1$ (can ve shown by AM-GM). Now, as the expression is homogeneous, we can scale down all $a_i$ to half. So $a_1,...,a_n=\frac{1}{2}$, so now $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n=\frac{n}{2}$, and $E= \frac{2n}{5}$ which would be it's maximum value. And we are done. I checked the answer and indeed it's $\frac{2n}{5}$, but they used a different solution. Is this solution correct?

Comment: It is not homogeneous. You probably mean symmetric. But this alone does not suffice to conclude that the maximum value is attained when all $a_i$'s are equal. It could as well be attained at various points, e.g. if $n=2$, attained both at some $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$.

Comment: The easiest way to solve is still Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @openspace what is Lagrange multipler and how to apply it here?

Comment: @AnneBauval oh, i meant homogeneous. If it's not homogeneous, then my solution is wrong

Comment: It is clearly not. May be you don't have the correct [definition of homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function)?

Comment: [Read this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeMultiplier.html)

Comment: Or this: [Wikipedia, Lagrange multiplier, Single constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Single_constraint_2).

Comment: @AnneBauval that all the terms should have same degree. I'm sorry i misunderstood the degree if the expression's terms

Comment: @AnneBauval hello, can you please tell me if the knowledge of high school maths is enough for knowing Lagrange multiplers? Because i see some terms i don't have idea about? Are the prerequisites of it beyond the scope of Olympiads/high school math? Thank you

Comment: Probably not (at least not in my country). But if you know partial derivatives, this should be sufficient to apply Lagrange to your exercise: at a local extremum for $f$ defined on the set $\{a\in\Bbb R_+^n\mid g(a)=n/2\},$ $(\partial_1f,\dots,\partial_nf)=\lambda(\partial_1g,\dots,\partial_ng)$ for some real number $\lambda.$

Comment: Sorry, my "probably not" was unclear. I meant the knowledge of highschool is *probably not enough*, and the prerequisites forLagrange multipliers are *probably beyond* the scope of high school.

Comment: An easier approach (using just high-school ideas), is to use the tangent line method at $ x = 1/2$. Show that $ x/(1+x^2) \leq 0.48x + 0.16$ for $x > 0$, sum it up, and the conclusion follows. We can do this up to $ \sum a_i \leq n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your solution does not work because the expression is not homogenous.

Another way to see that this reasoning is incorrect, is to extrapolate your reasoning to the case of $ \sum a_i >> n$. Specifically, consider

> If $a+b = 10$, what is the maximum of $ \frac{ a}{ 1+a^2} + \frac{b}{1+b^2}$?

If your assumption about scaling is correct, then we'd say that the maximum occurs at $ a = b = 5$, with value of $ 2 \times \frac{5}{1+25} < \frac{1}{2} $. But clearly, if we had $ a = 1$, the value is at least $\frac{1}{2}$, so the $ a= b = 5$ does not achieve the maximum.

The conclusion (max occurs when all values are equal) is true when the sum is low enough.
When the sum is large, this no longer works. The reason behind that is convexity.
The second derivative of $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is $\frac{2x(x^2-3)}{(x^2+1)^3}$, which is positive for $x > \sqrt{3}$.
So, if $\sum a_i = An$ for $ A > \sqrt{3}$, then for $f(a_i, a_2, \ldots, a_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{1+a_i^2}$,
$$f(A, A, \ldots , A, A) < f(A, A, \ldots, A, 2A - \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}) < \ldots < f( nA - (n-1)\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}, \ldots , \sqrt{3}, ).$$
In fact, we can conclude that at the maximum (for any sum), at most 1 value will be $ > \sqrt{3}$ (since otherwise we can replace $a_i, a_j$ with $ \sqrt{3}, a_i + a_j - \sqrt{3} $).

---

Generalizing your question, we can show

> Given positive $a_i$ such that $ \sum a_i = A n$ for $ A \leq 1$, then $ \sum \frac{a_i}{1+a_i^2}$ is maximized when $a_i $ are all equal to $ \frac{ \sum a_i } { n}$.

One way to show this is the tangent line method:
Prove that for $ 0 < A \leq 1$ (representing $ \frac{\sum a_i}{n}$) and $ b \geq 0$, we have
$$   \frac{b}{1+b^2} \leq \frac{A}{1+A^2} + \frac{1-A^2}{(1+A^2)^2} (b-A).  $$
The RHS is the value of the tangent line at $ (A, \frac{A}{1+A^2})$ to $ y = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$, evaluated at $b$.
If you expand and simplify the inequality, with some work it becomes $(A-b)^2[ (A^2 - 1)b - 2A ] \leq 0$, so it's true in our given domain.

Now, summing up across $ b = a_i$, and using $ \sum a_i = nA$, we get

$$ \sum \frac{a_i}{1+a_i^2} \leq n\times \frac{A}{1+A^2} + \frac{1-A^2}{(1+A^2)^2} \sum (a_i-A)  =  n\times \frac{A}{1+A^2}.$$

Notes

- Consider the tangent line inequality for a fixed $A = \frac{1}{2}$. We have $\frac{b}{1+b^2} \leq \frac{2}{5} + \frac{12}{25} ( b - \frac{1}{2}) \Leftrightarrow \frac{(1-2b)^2(3b+4) } { 25(b^2 + 1 ) } \geq 0$. You can recognize the general form, and proving it just requires you to be careful with the algebra.
- We can't simply use Jensen's inequality, because the second derivative is positive at large values.
- Conversely, if $ \sum a_i = na$ with $ a> 1$, then there is a large enough $N$, such that for any $ n> N$, the maximum occurs when not all of the values are equal. With more work, we can show is that all but 1 value are equal.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your elaborated answer. But what do you mean by "So, when ∑ai
 is large (Valid at least for >3√n
), the all-equal case is a local minimum." ? Does that mean that the expression would give it's minimum value for the all equal case when sum of all a_i s are >√3 n?

Comment: @math_learner I cleaned that up more. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not induction? Trivially $E_1\leq \frac{2}{5}.$ Suppose $E_{n-1}\leq \frac{2(n-1)}{5}.$ Consider now $E_n$ as a function of $a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}$ defined on the compact tetrahedron $a_i\geq 0$ and $a_n=\frac{n}{2}-a_1-\ldots-a_n\geq 0.$ The maximum of $E_n$ is either reached on the boundary -namely is $\frac{2(n-1)}{5}$ from the induction hypothesis, or is reached in the interior in a point where the gradient is zero. Now
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a_i}E_n=(a_n^2-a_i^2)\times P_i$$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1,$ where we do not care of the positive quantity $P_i.$ The gradient is zero if and only if $a_1=\cdots=a_n=1/2.$ The value on this  point is $\frac{2n}{5}$ and cannot be a minimum (if not, the max of $E_n$ would be reached at some other interior point of the tetraedron and the gradient would also vanish on this hypothetic point). The induction is extended.

Comment: Naive induction doesn't work. How are you implementing the condition that $ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = n/2$? With that, it forces $a_{n+1} = 1/2$.  $\quad$ (Sorry for the double message, I thought I had a workaround, but I couldn't push through. We need to deal with the case where $ a_{n+1} > n/2$, and so can't simply resolve to $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \leq n/2$. )

Comment: Thanks for your remark, I have edited an $n$ into $n-1.$ Up to this, I do not understand well your message.

Comment: You are assuming that the max of $E_{n-1}$ is $2(n-1)/5$, subject to the condition that $a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_{n-1} = (n-1)/2$. How do you extend this to $n$ variables? EG What happens if $a_1 = (n+0.5)/2$, $a_2 = a_2 = ... = a_n = 1/[4(n-1)]$? How do you apply the induction hypothesis, when there is no $n-1$ terms that sum up to $(n-1)/2$?

Comment: Good point, there is a flaw, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more complicated approach, which aims to supplement Calvin Lin's excellent answer.

Let $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$, then this function attains its maximum at $f(1)=1/2$. It is also concave and increasing on $[0,1]$, and decreasing on $(1,\infty)$, verified by checking $f'$ and $f''$. Let also $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = nA$ for $0\leq a_i, i=1\ldots,n$ and $0 \leq A \leq 1$.

Now if $I=\{i:a_i \geq 1\}$ and $J=\{j:a_j < 1\}$, then let us define $b_i = 1$ if $i\in I$ and $b_i = a_i + \theta_i S$ if $i \in J$, where $S = \sum_{i\in I} a_i - b_i = -|I| + \sum_{i\in I}a_i$, and $0 \leq \theta_i = \frac{1-a_i}{\sum_{j\in J}1-a_j} \leq 1.$ It is then easy to see that:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n b_i=|I| + \sum_{i\in J}a_i+\theta_i S =|I| -|I| +\sum_{i\in I} a_i +\sum_{i\in J}a_i= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = nA.
$$

Furthermore since $n=|I|+|J|$ and $A \leq 1$:
$$
S = \sum_{i\in I}a_i - b_i = -|I| + nA - \sum_{i\in J}a_i = |J| - n + nA - \sum_{i\in J}a_i\leq |J| - \sum_{i\in J}a_i = \sum_{i\in J}1 - a_i,
$$
thus for $i\in J$:
$$
b_i = a_i + \theta_i S = a_i + \frac{\sum_{j\in I}a_j - b_j}{\sum_{j\in J}1 - a_j}(1 - a_i)\leq a_i + \frac{\sum_{i\in J}1 - a_i}{\sum_{i\in J}1 - a_i}(1-a_i)=1.
$$

This, and the properties of $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$ imply that $f(a_i)\leq f(b_i)$ for all $i=1,\ldots, n$.

Finally,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nf(a_i)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n f(b_i) \leq nf\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} b_i \right)=nf(A),
$$
where the last inequality is just Jensen's. Equality is attained when $a_1=\cdots=a_n=A$.